# How to use a PHP regular expression to parse an iframe tag?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use `preg_match` to extract the width of a YouTube video from the embed code.

The code is something like:

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/3uw-nUvGrBY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and I would like to extract `width="480"`.

I've tried:

```
/width="[0-9]+"/
/width=\"[0-9]+\"/
/width=.[0-9]+./
```

but none of them work.  If I remove the final double quotes, and the numbers, I can extract `width="` but I can't get beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/3uw-nUvGrBY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
preg_match('/.*width="(\d+)".*/', $string, $match);\
echo $match[1];
```

But I'm sure, the PHP or JS DOM is able to do it with less pain...

Comment: How would I go about using the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Your actual source might be formatted differently. Your example html snippet looks too exemplary. Try this:

```
preg_match('#\b(width\s*=)\s*["\']?(\d+)#i', $source, $match);
print $match[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ptn = "/(?<=width=\")\d*(?=\")/";
$str = '<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/3uw-nUvGrBY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
preg_match($ptn, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0]; // 480
```